# How to show custom progress bar based on API data in react-native

Tags: react-native, progress-bar

How can I show the progress of the delivery based on API data in react native.

I referred to step-indicators modules but not suitable for my requirement.

How to show a progress bar as shown in the below image in react native.

[image]